# Study of a parametric function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

I would like to study this function for $x\geq 0$, $\forall b,d \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$
y=\frac{b+dx}{1-b-dx}
$$
Can I say that it is monotone increasing (decreasing) over $x$ in its domain for $d>0$ ($d<0$)?

Comment: This is mistagged as functional analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{b+dx}{1-b-dx}\right]=\frac{d}{\left(1-b-dx\right)^{2}}
$$
and hence the function is monotone increasing (decreasing) for $d>0$
($d<0$).

Answer (score 0):

by the quotient rule we get after simplifications for the first derivative
$$y'=\frac{d}{(dx+b-1)^2}$$ now you can consider the cases $d>0$ or $d<0$